# jsf 1.2 popup dialogue box on delete button press

Tags: primefaces, jsf-1.2

I need to have a confirmation dialogue box onclick of a delete button. I am using Jsf 1.2 can I use primeFace or RichFaces to do it? or what is the approch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this: [ConfirmDialog](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/confirmDialog.jsf)